# Excel Format Range x-achsis date

Tags: excel, graph, scaling

I have a chart which shoudl only show the data of the last 10 days. The graph change automatically based on the actual data, since it only should show the last 10 days. So i create a name range for the x-achsis and y-achsis.

```
=Offset(Data!$B$14;Count(Data!$K$14:$K$333)-10;;10;1)
```

So in column B only the last 10 days with data are selected. In the table no dates occur where no data is available. But the graph still shows me the dates in between even if there is no data. How can i solve that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C7hm.jpg

---

Thanks robrados for your answer. But i have the data already in the order i want to show them. I just want the graph to show the data without adding dates by himself. I attached how i created the graph.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBVw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Schmid

You need to use array formulas to solve that problem.
Look at the uploaded image: you have to enter the following 2 array formulas and drag them over 10 rows:

{=INDEX(A:A,LARGE(IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B)),ROW(A1)))}
-> With this formula you evaluate the last 10 dates with data entries (without empty cells)

{=INDEX(B:B,LARGE(IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B)),ROW(A1)))}
-> this formula will give you the values which match for the date

Don't forget to confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of only pressing the Enter-key)

format the X axis with the following option: Categories in reverse order

I hope this solution can solve your problem.

[Array formula, values with last 10 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUHi8.png)

[view of the formulas in each cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8uOA.png)

Update:

look You have to format the x - axis as following: Axis Type = Text axis
look at the following screenshot 
[image: x axis format]